# Use series method to obtain a general solution of the Cauchy-Euler Equation $x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac 34y=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use series method to obtain a general  solution of the Cauchy-Euler Equation $$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac 34y=0.$$

To be very honest, I didn't understand the language of the question for it says, "series method". I assumed that it intended to say,

> "Find a power series solution of the Cauchy-Euler Equation $$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac 34y=0.$$"

But this is again ambiguous, for ut specifies, no point(s) around which I am supposed to find a power series solution.

I assumed that, they intended to find tge power series solution about the regular singular point $x=0.$

As, $x=0$ was a regular singular point, I tried applying the method of Frobenius to find a power series solution about $0$.

I proceeded as:

Let $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^{n+r}$ be a solution to the equation where, $r$ is a constant that nay be determined with the assumption that $c_0\neq 0.$

This means, $y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)c_nx^{n+r-1}$ and $y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)(n+r-1)c_nx^{n+r-2}.$ Substituting these in the original equation we find, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big [(n+r)(n+r-1)-(n+r)+\frac 34\big ]c_nx^{n+r}=0.$$

Hence, we obtain the recurrence, relation $ [(n+r)(n+r-1)-(n+r)+\frac 34\big ]c_n=0$ for all $n\geq 0.$

If $n=0$ then, $(4r^2-8r+3)c_0=0$ and as, $c_0\neq 0$ so, $4r^2-8r+3=0$ is actually the indicial equation. We find, $r_1=\frac 32,r_2=\frac 12.$

Now, if $r=r_1$ then, from the recurrence relation we have(under the value of $r=r_1$) $$c_n(n+n^2)=0$$ for all $n\geq 1.$

---

But here is the problem, as this means $c_n=0,\forall n\geq 1.$ I dont know, where I went wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I feel that the problem is not in work, really. The thing is, the particular integral of this ODE will simply contain just two terms, but then what is meant by the series method?

Comment: You haven't gone wrong anywhere.  A Cauchy-Euler equation will have power functions (not series, just single terms) as solutions

Comment: @messenger Oh! Thanks for confirming. So, then how to solve the problem? What did they mean by "series method" ?

Comment: Perhaps they wanted to emphasize the connection between Euler-Cauchy with characteristic polynomial and general regular singularities with the indicial equation of the Frobenius series.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Mind showing it formally ?

Comment: What do you mean? You already did that perfectly, showing that the non-zero part of the solution reduces to the indicial equation. Now you just need to observe that you would get the same equation as the characteristic equation of the Euler-Cauchy DE.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ok, but then ? I am not sure what you meant by "characteristic equation of the Euler-Cauchy DE."

Comment: @LutzLehmann I have only heard about characteristic equation of a matrix.

Comment: This is related. If you make the equation into an equivalent first-order system with Euler-Cauchy structure (similar with linear DE with constant coefficients), then the system matrix has the same characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculations are correct. With $r=\frac 32$, you have found $c_n=0$ for all $n \geq 1$. So

$$y_1(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^{n+3/2} = c_0 x^{3/2}$$

Checking, $y_1'(x) = \frac 32 c_0 x^{1/2}, y_1''(x) = c_0 \frac 34 x^{-1/2}$, and

$$ x^2 y_1''(x) - x y_1'(x) + \frac 34 y = \left(\frac 34 - \frac 32 + \frac 34\right) c_0 x^{3/2} = 0 $$

so $y_1=c_0 x^{3/2}$ is in fact a solution.

You have certainly used the series method which begins by supposing $y(x)$ can be written as a power series. This function can still be considered a series, just with all terms except one equal to zero.

With $r=\frac 12$, we find $c_n(n^2-n)=0$ implying $c_n = 0$ for all $n \geq 2$. And the $c_1 x^{3/2}$ term in $y_2(x)$ is just redundant with $y_1(x)$. So the full solution set is

$$ y = C_1 x^{3/2} + C_2 x^{1/2} $$

Comment: @aschelper Thanks, I got badly confused down the line. +1 from me!

Comment: (+1) I was working on an alternate approach when you answered. I have included that approach in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If we set $n=0$ in your equation, we get
$$
r^2-2r+\frac34=0
$$
which has roots $r=\frac12$ and $r=\frac32$.
This indicates that $x^{1/2}$ and $x^{3/2}$ are solutions. In fact, no matter what is substituted for $n$, the terms for $x^{1/2}$ and $x^{3/2}$ are the only that do not vanish.

Since this is a linear equation, any linear combination of these gives a solution. That is,
$$
y=ax^{3/2}+bx^{1/2}
$$

---

Here is an alternate approach:

Note that
$$
(xD)^2=x^2D^2+xD\tag1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
x^2D^2-xD+\frac34
&=(xD)^2-2xD+\frac34\tag{2a}\\
&=\left(xD-\frac32\right)\left(xD-\frac12\right)\tag{2b}\\[3pt]
&=\left(x^{5/2}Dx^{-3/2}\right)\left(x^{3/2}Dx^{-1/2}\right)\tag{2c}\\[6pt]
&=x^{5/2}D^2x^{-1/2}\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ apply $(1)$
$\text{(2b):}$ factor
$\text{(2c):}$ apply integrating factors to rewrite each operator
$\text{(2d):}$ combine operators

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
x^{5/2}D^2x^{-1/2}y&=0\tag{3a}\\[3pt]
D^2x^{-1/2}y&=0\tag{3b}\\[3pt]
x^{-1/2}y&=ax+b\tag{3c}\\[3pt]
y&=ax^{3/2}+bx^{1/2}\tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$

---

Note that the equation $r^2-2r+\frac34=0$ shows up in both of these approaches. That is the characteristic equation for this differential operator.